# Match drop down value and array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to match drop down list value and an array. Then I got some problems.

```
var authorArray =["a","b","c"];
```

and the name of the author must match the name of the book

```
<form name="myForm" action="">
    Author's name: <input type="text"  name="authorName"><br>
```

and here is a drop down list

```
<select name="selectBook" id="bookName">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option id="bookA"value="q">q</option>
    <option id="bookB"value="r">r</option>
    <option id="bookC"value="s">s</option>
</select>
```

If author `a` match book `q` then output book information `x`

If author `b` match book `r` then output book information `y`

If author `c` match book `q` then output book information `z`

the output must in a textarea box

```
<input type="button" value="RETRIEVE"> 
<textarea name="infoBox"  cols="120"></textarea>
```

How to do that?
Thanks for help

Comment: What is your problem with your example ??

Comment: So you want to map a 2-dim key to a value? (Author, Book) => Information?

Comment: All i have done are fail. I don't know how to match author and book. that is the most important for me

Comment: to fast:
yes! That is the i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do something like this with objects:

```js
var authors = {
               a: {
                   books: {
         q:"x"
            }
               },
               b: {
                   books: {
         r:"y"
     }
               },
               c: {
                   books: {
        q:"z"
                  }
               }
}

function findBookByName(name){
  for(a in authors){
     for(b in authors[a]){
        if(authors[a][b].hasOwnProperty(name)) return authors[a][b][name];      
     }
  }
  
  return "NOT FOUND"
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
   var selectBook = document.getElementById("bookName"),
       buttonRetrieve = document.getElementById("btnRetrieve"),
       infoBox = document.getElementsByName("infoBox");
   
   buttonRetrieve.addEventListener('click', function(){
     var result = findBookByName(selectBook.value);
     infoBox[0].value = result;
   
   })


})
```

```html
<select name="selectBook" id="bookName">
    <option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
    <option id="bookA"value="q">q</option>
    <option id="bookB"value="r">r</option>
    <option id="bookC"value="s">s</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="btnRetrieve" value="RETRIEVE"> 
<textarea name="infoBox"  cols="120"></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks but maybe I didn't explain my question clearly.
there has a input box, the input value must match the value in array.
that means both input value and drop down value are correct, the textarea box will give the information .
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

In order to map a 2-dim key to substantially distinct values you might setup a 2-dim 'array' like:

```
var Info_for_Author_and_Book = {
 'author_a' : {
   'book_q' : "Info for a, q",
   ...
   'book_s' : "Info for a, s"
  },
  ...
 'author_c' : {
   'book_q' : "Info for c, q",
   ...
   'book_s' : "Info for c, s"
  }
 }
```

You access the info data by:

```
var selected_info = (Info_for_Author_and_Book[author] && Info_for_Author_and_Book[author][book]) || "Not available";
```

Comment: It seems to be a little difficult... if i have 100 author, this solution will become a trouble

Comment: When you actually need different infos for every author x book you might have no other choice.. but you might be able to automate it?! is there no scheme for teh info?